# Firebase 3 with ionic 2 google authentication

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am new to mobile app development and ionic 2. I get the google authentication working fine for a web app using angularfire2 but that doesn't work on a mobile device (yet?).
I am using ionic 2 version 2.0.0-beta.35 and firebase 3.2.1

Searching led me to the understanding that for the time being I need to use the google+ plugin for cordova, which I have installed.

I am trying this method in my ts code:

```
loginWithGooglePlugin()
{
    return Observable.create(observer =>
    {
        // note for iOS the googleplus plugin requires ENABLE_BITCODE to be turned off in the Xcode
        window.plugins.googleplus.login(
            {
                'scopes': 'profile email', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
                'webClientId': '_google_client_app_id_.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'offline': true, // optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
            },
            function (authData)
            {
                console.log('got google auth data:', JSON.stringify(authData, null, 2));
                let provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(authData.idToken, authData.accessToken);
                firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then((success) =>
                {
                    console.log('success!', JSON.stringify(success, null, 2));
                    observer.next(success);
                }, (error) =>
                {
                    console.log('error', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
                });
            },
            function (msg)
            {
                this.error = msg;
            }
        );
    });
}
```

But the compiler keeps complaining about two things:
1. window.plugins is unknown. How can I convince ts that it's there?

2. There is no `credential` on the `GoogleAuthProvider` object. Searching yielded this link: [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GoogleAuthProvider) which says there was a method `getCredential`, which is not recognized either.

My `typings` seem to be fine. `GoogleAuthProvider` itself is recognized.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is a bug in the typescript definitions. The Firebase team has been notified and is working on a fix. In the meantime use the following workaround:

```
(<any> firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider).credential
```

Answer (score -1):

In my **Ionic2 RC1 + Firebase3.5 + AngularFire2.beta5** project I had the same problem... Google Auth with Popup worked in Browser but not in my Android .APK

Firstly, I add *192.168.1.172* to my Firebase Console authorized domain list and `<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.172:8100"/>` to my *config.xml*.

After this, I found that **[installing Cordova InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#installation)** plugin solves my problem definitively.

I didn't need to modify my code, only plug and play, exactly like David East says in his [Social login with Ionic blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/social-login-with-ionic_77.html).